# Foxconn X55 modem disconnects without any reason

Tags: arch-linux, thinkpad, modem-manager

My Thinkpad P1 gen4 has a Foxconn Snapdragon X55 wwan-modem. I'm running Arch (6.7.2-arch1-1) with Gnome (45.3) on it.

I updated firmware of modem to T99W175.F0.1.0.0.9.TF.008.079 . I also symlinked FCC-unlock. The modem is working, I can connect and use it.

```
$ ls -la /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   56 22. Jan 22:20 105b:e0ab -> /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/105b:e0ab
```

But without any reason, the connection is diconnected, the modem is lost and comes back with new device-id (+1).

In log I see, while its working, every 10-20 seconds:

```
Jan 30 08:27:31 thinkpad kernel: sequence number glitch prev=7 curr=0
```

....if it dies:

```
Jan 30 13:18:51 thinkpad kernel: mhi-pci-generic 0000:08:00.0: firmware crashed (6)
Jan 30 13:18:51 thinkpad kernel: wwan0: Failed to queue TX buf (-5)
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [modem1] port 'wwan0mbim0' no longer controllable, reprobing
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad NetworkManager[1300]: <info>  [1706617132.0900] device (wwan0mbim0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad kernel: wwan wwan0: port wwan0qcdm0 disconnected
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad kernel: wwan wwan0: port wwan0mbim0 disconnected
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad kernel: wwan wwan0: port wwan0at0 disconnected
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <wrn> [/dev/wwan0mbim0] MBIM error: Device must be open to send commands
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <wrn> [/dev/wwan0mbim0] MBIM error: Device must be open to send commands
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <wrn> [/dev/wwan0mbim0] MBIM error: Device must be open to send commands
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <wrn> [/dev/wwan0mbim0] MBIM error: Device must be open to send commands
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <wrn> [/dev/wwan0mbim0] MBIM error: Device must be open to send commands
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <wrn> [modem1/wwan0mbim0/mbim] Couldn't properly close QMI device: Device must be open to send commands
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad passimd[2919]: resetting Passim-D3AC
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad passimd[2919]: Emitting PropertyChanged('Status'='running')
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad passimd[2919]: signal_name: StateChanged (is)
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [base-manager] port wwan0qcdm0 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0'
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [base-manager] port wwan0mbim0 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0'
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [base-manager] port wwan0at0 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0'
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [base-manager] port wwan0 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0'
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad dnsmasq[1523]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad NetworkManager[1300]: <info>  [1706617132.1380] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad NetworkManager[1300]: <warn>  [1706617132.1388] modem-broadband[wwan0mbim0]: failed to disconnect modem: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1”
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad evolution[3665]: Network disconnected.  Forced offline.
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad kernel: wwan wwan0: port wwan0qcdm0 attached
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad kernel: wwan wwan0: port wwan0mbim0 attached
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad kernel: wwan wwan0: port wwan0at0 attached
Jan 30 13:18:52 thinkpad vivaldi-stable.desktop[2939]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Jan 30 13:18:53 thinkpad passimd[2919]: signal_name: StateChanged (is)
Jan 30 13:18:54 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [wwan0mbim0/mbim] MBIM device is not QMI capable
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0] creating modem with plugin 'foxconn' and '4' ports
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [base-manager] modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:08:00.0' successfully created
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [modem2/wwan0mbim0/mbim] MBIM device is QMI capable
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad ModemManager[1372]: <msg> [modem2] state changed (unknown -> disabled)
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad NetworkManager[1300]: <info>  [1706617136.5651] manager: (wwan0mbim0): new Broadband device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad NetworkManager[1300]: <info>  [1706617136.5655] device (wwan0mbim0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad NetworkManager[1300]: <info>  [1706617136.5660] device (wwan0mbim0): modem state 'enabling'
Jan 30 13:18:56 thinkpad NetworkManager[1300]: <info>  [1706617136.5666] device (wwan0mbim0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

I also tried to set card to 3g+4G without 5G, but this did not help too.

Any ideads how to fix this?

Comment: Does updating the firmware again solve the issue?  See: [Arch Forum Post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=273212)

Comment: @eyoung100 No, this did not help.